# Is there a way to get A SET radio buttons to lose their focus when clicked?

Tags: html

I have a web page with about 10 questions, consisting of ABCD answers. Each ABCD has its own radio button followed by the answer.

If you click one radio button, you are able to use the up/down arrow keys to scroll through the answer. I want this feature to be disabled, because I will have certain pages containing 50 answers per page.

Any help or thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: A code sample would be appreciated be us.

Comment: You need to do this with Javascript

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions would be creating those radio buttons not grouped. Than you will have to write some javascript to implement grouping on your own so when you select one of the radio buttons the others from your group get unselected. When the radio buttons are not grouped (different name attribute) you cannot navigate through them with up/down key.